# Can ffprobe detect the language of blu-ray titles?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I use a [shell script](https://github.com/git-developer/vaapi-video-converter/blob/develop/entrypoint) to transcode videos using FFMPEG with VAAPI (hardware transcoding) support. The output file should contain the video and a single audio track in a language given by the user.

The following command is used to detect the audio language of the source streams:

`ffprobe -select_streams a -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language`

It works for MKV (`-i video.mkv`) and MPEG-TS (`-i video.ts`) files:

```
[STREAM]
index=1
TAG:language=eng
[/STREAM]
```

It does not work for blu-ray discs (`-i bluray:.`):

```
[STREAM]
index=1
[/STREAM]
```

Additional info:

- Tested against `ffmpeg-20200213-6d37ca8` with `libbluray-j2se-1.1.2.jar`
- VLC is able to show the languages when the blu-ray is played.
- `mkvmerge` is able to detect the languages from a playlist (e.g. `BDMV/PLAYLIST/00001.mpls`).

My question: Is it possible to detect the languages using `ffprobe`? Or will I have to use another tool for that task?

Comment: The same question was reported by a different user on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/91v73p/how_to_get_audiosubtitle_language_of_a_stream/).